# In unit testing, what's the difference between fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.query and document.getElement?

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to Angular unit tests and was looking at some tests written by others. I see the attempts to access elements three different ways:

- `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#hello'))`
- `fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#hello')`
- `document.getElementById('#hello')`

Is there any difference/best practice for using these?

Comment: thats a good question, take a look and see of this explains. In case you are new to angular testing, I would recommend you to read https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 . It covers almost all basic scenarios of testing that is required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **html:**

```
<div id="shan">Hey there</div>
```

1. **fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#hello'))**

It is used to get "[DebugElement](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement)" for a DOM object. More info can be found [here in offical doc](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By#css). You can pass `id` as `By.css('#hello')` , `class` as `By.css('.hello')` , or you can also elements with ways such as `By.css('div')` or `By.css('some-app-component')`

`DebugElement` is an Angular class that contains all kinds of references and methods relevant to investigate an **element** or **component**

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#shan'))
```

will return

> DebugElement__PRE_R3__{listeners: [], parent: DebugElement__PRE_R3__{listeners: [], parent: null, *debugContext: DebugContext*{view: ..., nodeIndex: ..., nodeDef: ..., elDef: ..., elView: ...}, nativeNode: Hey there, properties: Object{}, attributes: Object{ng-version: ...}, classes: Object{}, styles: Object{}, childNodes: [...], nativeElement: Hey there}, *debugContext: DebugContext*{view: Object{def: ..., parent: ..., viewContainerParent: ..., parentNodeDef: ..., context: ..., component: ..., nodes: ..., state: ..., root: ..., renderer: ..., oldValues: ..., disposables: ..., initIndex: ...}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object{nodeIndex: ..., parent: ..., renderParent: ..., bindingIndex: ..., outputIndex: ..., checkIndex: ..., flags: ..., childFlags: ..., directChildFlags: ..., childMatchedQueries: ..., matchedQueries: ..., matchedQueryIds: ..., references: ..., ngContentIndex: ..., childCount: ..., bindings: ..., bindingFlags: ..., outputs: ..., element: ..., provider: ..., text: ..., query: ..., ngContent: ...}, elDef: Object{nodeIndex: ..., parent: ..., renderParent: ..., bindingIndex: ..., outputIndex: ..., checkIndex: ..., flags: ..., childFlags: ..., directChildFlags: ..., childMatchedQueries: ..., matchedQueries: ..., matchedQueryIds: ..., references: ..., ngContentIndex: ..., childCount: ..., bindings: ..., bindingFlags: ..., outputs: ..., element: ..., provider: ..., text: ..., query: ..., ngContent: ...}, elView: Object{def: ..., parent: ..., viewContainerParent: ..., parentNodeDef: ..., context: ..., component: ..., nodes: ..., state: ..., root: ..., renderer: ..., oldValues: ..., disposables: ..., initIndex: ...}}, nativeNode: Hey there, properties: Object{}, attributes: Object{id: 'shan'}, classes: Object{}, styles: Object{}, childNodes:[DebugNode__PRE_R3__{listeners: ..., parent: ..., _debugContext: ...,
>   ..nativeNode: ...}], nativeElement: Hey there, name: 'div'}

---

2. **fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#hello')**

`nativeElement` returns a reference to the DOM element which can also come under `debugElement` as stated above.You can use it do actions such as `click()` event in test cases.

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#hello').click(); // this will create a click event over this element.
```

It works for querying both `class` 
 something like `(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.hello'))` as well as `id`.

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#shan')
```

will return

```
<div _ngcontent-a-c0="" id="shan">Hey there</div>
```

---

3. **document.getElementById('hello')**

This is our good old way to access an `id` (not a `class`). You can't access `class` by doing something like

```
document.getElementById('.hello') // will return null
```

**Also, note that you don't need to pass `#` in this function argument**.

```
document.getElementById('#hello') // will return null
```

It should be avoided while working with `angular` because angular has its own `ChangeDetection` which requires it to be worked with `fixtures`. By directly calling `document` , you'll end up banging your head on the wall , trying to figure out *why is the element coming as `null`*

```
document.getElementById('shan')
```

will return

```
<div _ngcontent-a-c0="" id="shan">Hey there</div>
```

[Since you are new to unit testing in angular, you can refer my series of articles on Unit testing](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) . I hope this will help you. Cheers!